# jqgrid - Postdata cannot be calculated in runtime

Tags: php, jqgrid

I tried to pass in `PostData` that is calculated in runtime, but it doesnot work.

Something simple like this doesnot work(`$uid` is not calculated in runtime):

```
$conn = new PDO(DB_DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
jqGridDB::query($conn,"SET NAMES utf8");
$grid = new jqGridRender($conn);
$query= 'SELECT employeename FROM employees where uid =?';
$grid->SelectCommand = $query;
$grid->dataType = 'json';

$uid=$_REQUEST['uid'];

$uid=($uid+2)/9; 

$aux = array($uid);

// Let the grid create the model
$grid->setColModel(null, $aux);

// Set some grid options
$grid->setGridOptions(array(
    "rowNum"=>10,
    "height"=>"200″,
    "rowList"=>array(10,20,30),
    "sortname"=>"id",
   "postData"=>array("uid"=>$uid)
));

$grid->renderGrid('#grid','#pager',true, null, $aux, true,true);
```

Called using `?uid=16` in my URL. `((16+2)/9=2`. When I used `$uid=2` in replace of `$uid=$uid/9+2` and it works fine but I need $uid to be calculated in run time -In the future, I need to encrypt the uid passed in as REQUEST parameter.).

Does `JQGrid` support real time calculation of the `PostData`, or is the `PostData` precalculated in someway since the above simple example doesnot work?

Thanks in advance.

---

Solved the problem. The calculation is called twice for some reason. 
So when I want $uid to be 2, I have to set the $REQUEST uid number to suppose the "$uid=($uid+2)/9;" being called twice. Could be some bug in JQGrid.

Comment: Are you 100% sure $_REQUEST['uid'] contains data? Because otherwise your calculation would result in null.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I print it out under $uid=$_REQUEST['uid'] statement and it print "2". However, for unknown mechanism in jqgrid, I think $uid is passed into the postData as 0.

Comment: I edited the code to show the complete picture. When I print $uid out under the calculation, it shows "2" which is correct.  When I replace the ($uid+2)/9 with 2, it works. So some special mechanism in JQGrid mess this up, I am thinking some precalculation of the postData?